# How to do a select that display 2 results based on 2 different where - TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, sum

I have these 2 queries, they both bring info from same table but different WHERE condition, How can I execute this in just one query that gives me the result as a table of 2 column one column with value of query one and second column with value of query 2.

QUERY 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS FirstColumn 

FROM MyTable

WHERE ThisValue !=1150 and Date = today-1;
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SecondColumn 

FROM MyTable

WHERE ThisValue = 1130 AND
((Station_Date = today-1 AND Station_Time > 120000)
or (Station_Date = today AND Station_Time <= 120000));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional sums:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN ThisValue !=1150 and Date = today-1 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS FirstColumn,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ThisValue = 1130 AND (
           (Station_Date = today-1 AND Station_Time > 120000)
           OR (Station_Date = today AND Station_Time <= 120000)
        ) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS SecondColumn
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: It works perfectly , this is exactly what I need, I'm new here maybe my question looks so easy and dumb

Comment: @Arturo: no problem, your question was not dumb... We all are learning!

Comment: Yes, I was trying to hit the green check but I needed to wait more minutes, but there it is, THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the same conditions in the `WHERE` clause with `OR` operator to avoid scanning full table data as following:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN THISVALUE != 1150
             AND DATE = TODAY - 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS FIRSTCOLUMN,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN THISVALUE = 1130
             AND((STATION_DATE = TODAY - 1
                  AND STATION_TIME > 120000)
                 OR(STATION_DATE = TODAY
                    AND STATION_TIME <= 120000)) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS SECONDCOLUMN
FROM
    MYTABLE
WHERE
    ( THISVALUE != 1150
      AND DATE = TODAY - 1 ) -- FIRST CONDITION
    OR ( THISVALUE = 1130 -- SECOND CONDITION TILL END 
         AND ( ( STATION_DATE = TODAY - 1
                 AND STATION_TIME > 120000 )
               OR ( STATION_DATE = TODAY
                    AND STATION_TIME <= 120000 ) ) )
```

Cheers!!